# Calling static method from constructor es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, static-methods

When I am trying to call a static method from constructor in javascript it says the method doesn't exist.

```
class TestClass {

    constructor(){
        this.staticMethod();
    }

    static staticMethod() {

    }
}
```

This works fine if i try to call a normal method from constructor. If static methods belongs to class instead of instance why it's not allowing them to call from constructor?

Comment: `this` refers to an instance, you are using static which is not tied to an instance, ...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
this.constructor.staticMethod()
```

can be used to avoid referring to the class directly (particularly useful for class inheritance and pasted code).

Comment: This was precisely what I needed.

Comment: I know I'm late to this party but is there a difference between `this.constructor.staticMethod()` and `TestClass.staticMethod()`?

Comment: @JonathonNordquist There's no difference, as long as it's called inside TestClass, but there's a difference for inherited classes.

Comment: I was searching for this exactly. The original poster of the question was only trying to call a static method in a normal way but I needed something that is polymorphic like in Java, when you use the object reference to call a static method instead of the class name and this is the exact answer I needed. Upvoted!

Answer (score 14):

You have to call it like this:

```
TestClass.staticMethod()
```

Comment: How can i be so dump.. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: works, but the day you want to rename it's not all that convenient